How to show this property of the Covariance matrix?

Hi all, may I ask how the pink highlighted equation is derived? By expanding the matrix, how does the remaining three terms result in n(avg X)(avg X)T? Apologies for the rather basic question, but am stuck at this section of the book I'm reading. Thanks.

Did you expand it? What did you get?

Typeset your question with Latex. Also, where do these notes come from?
